# Graphics benchmark for Android Extension Pack on Android Lollipop

Tags: graphics, android-5.0-lollipop, opengl-es-3.1

Right now I check Google Play for latest Graphics benchmarks. Got GFXBench 3.1 and Basemark ES 3.1 to verify OpenGLES 3.1 on my Android Lollipop. Is there any benchmark/Game/compatability test suite I can download to test Android Extension Pack (AEP) on top of GLES3.1?

Answer (score 0):

try to refer GFXBench 4.0
[Details](https://kishonti.net/news_single.jsp?id=22226761)

Comment: GFXBench 4.0 is not free to download. Is there any other benchmark/Game/compatability test suite freely available on Google Play?